# SignalR Hub injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Solution: using private `readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubcontext;` with `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICommandHandler, JoinChatHandler>();` resolve issue that is described below.

Brief description: I have client side code, that creates a connection to SignalR and send a HTTP request to gateway servise, which creates a command a send it to rabbitMq, different microservice handles this command. Problem is that when I inject HubContext and call method Whisper on client breakpoint inside this method is not hit.

Here is interface

```
public interface IChatClient
{
    Task<bool> Whisper(string message);
}
```

Here is my chatHub class

```
[Service(ServiceLifetime.Singleton)]
public class ChatHub : Hub<IChatClient>
{
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
    private readonly IChatService _chatService;
    private readonly ILogger<ChatHub> _logger;

    public ChatHub(IMessageService messageService, IChatService chatService, ILogger<ChatHub> logger)
    {
        _messageService = messageService;
        _chatService = chatService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Connection established");
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        //remove from rooms
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Whisper(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            //await Clients.Caller.ReceiveMessage(message);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error while writing to client.");
            Context.Abort();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is Handler

```
[Service(ServiceLifetime.Singleton)]
public class JoinChatHandler : ICommandHandler<JoinChat>
{
    private readonly ILogger<JoinChatHandler> _logger;
    private readonly IBusPublisher _busPublisher;
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> _hubContext;

    public JoinChatHandler(ILogger<JoinChatHandler> logger, IBusPublisher busPublisher,
        IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> hubContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _busPublisher = busPublisher;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task HandleAsync(JoinChat command, ICorrelationContext context)
    {
    var client = _hubContext.Clients.Client(command.ConnectionId);
        try
        {
          var t = await client.Whisper("AAA");
        }
          catch (Exception e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

No error thrown, also when OnConnectedAsync() is triggered. Absolutely no clue about possible issue.

And here is Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseAppMetrics();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services
    .AddSwagger()
    .AddPicheApiVersioning()
    .AddDispatchers()
    .AddServiceLocator<Program>()
    .AddInitializers(typeof(IMongoDbInitializer))
    .AddCustomMvc()
    .AddLogging()
    .AddRabbitMq()
    .AddJaeger()
    .AddOpenTracing()
    .AddSignalR();

builder.Services
    .AddMongo()
    .AddMongoRepository<ChatEntity>("chats")
    .AddMongoRepository<MessageEntity>("messages")
    .AddSingleton<ChatRepository>()
    .AddSingleton<MessageRepository>()
    .AddSingleton<ICommandHandler<JoinChat>, JoinChatHandler>();

builder.WebHost.UseLogging();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UsePicheCors()
    .UseAuthentication()
    .UseAuthorization()
    .UseServiceId()
    .UsePicheSwagger(app);

app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
        .AllowCredentials();
});

app.UseRabbitMq()
    .SubscribeCommand<CreateChat>()
    .SubscribeCommand<DeleteChat>()
    .SubscribeCommand<JoinChat>()
    .SubscribeCommand<LeaveChat>()
    .SubscribeCommand<SendMessage>()
    .SubscribeCommand<DeleteMessage>()
    .SubscribeCommand<UpdateMessage>()
    .SubscribeCommand<ShowPreviousMessages>();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Pls share the Startup.cs or Program.cs about the middleware register (JoinChatHandler )? You can refer [builder.Services.AddSingleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Just added it to question.

Comment: Add     `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICommandHandler, JoinChatHandler>();` before  `var app = builder.Build();`, then tell me the result.

Comment: I am waiting for your update, please let me know if the suggestion works for you or not.

Comment: Yeah i will provide it after 1 hour  Thanks for participating

Comment: Just updated Program.cs still no changes. (See question description .AddSingleton<ICommandHandler<JoinChat>, JoinChatHandler>();).

Comment: I believe problem is with private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> _hubContext; Just created another TestHub : Hub and injected it directly private readonly TestHub _hubContextTest; it works.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason for this issue. Just using `private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubcontext;` fix the issue ? without `AddSingleton`?

Comment: It works only when i inject hub directly not it context and without interface, like this private readonly TestHub _hubTest; and than await _hubContextTest.Whisper("TESTTTTTTTTTTTt"); triggers Whisper Method. Singleton is also needed.

Comment: In order to help more forum users who facing the same issue in the future, could you summarize the comments as answer? Using  `private readonly TestHub _hubTest` and use Singleton , and I also willing to summarize it 

Comment: I will, but after some hours of debugging I found that issue can be on client side, as when I test locally troughs swagger all works with code I provided in sample I mean IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> So next when I finally understand issue I will close this question and add summary.